# Database complex relations

Tags: php, database

I've tried to solve a problem for this system, but i'm not sure how to achieve this

let me explain what i want:

There is 1 Configuration table, that can contains multiple Sub-Configurations,

1 Sub-Configuration can contain multiple Sub-Sub-Configurations,

1 Sub-Sub-Configuration that can contain multiple Sub-Sub-Sub-Configurations

and 1 Sub-Sub-Sub-Configuration can contains Products:

sorry if this is confusing but here is the problem.

a Sub-Configuration can aslo contain only products. same for sub-sub-configurations.

and the tricky part of it that customers needs to have connections to all those sub-configurations and products.

---

so what i have is something like this with an example:

A is the Configuration and only configuration

A1, B1 and C1 are the Sub-Configurations of the Configuration A

A2, B2 and C2 are the Sub-Sub-Configuration of Sub-Configuration A1

A3, B3 and C3 are the Sub-Sub-Sub-Configuration of Sub-Sub-Configuration A2

and we have like cheese, chips and fish as products of Sub-Sub-Sub-Configuration A3.

but there also could be like an cow in C2.

The customer then has an true statement of Cheese and cow, meaning he has those products selected.

if any genius can help me with this problem, please let me know ;)

PS: i've added PHP, because this will be done in PHP code, connected to an database.

Comment: Looks like you want to make Many to one self referencing relation. You should add parent_id which reference configs parent, if its null it is "master".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eakethet mentions in a comment, a good solution is to create a single table for all the configurations that then references itself using a parent_id column.

I would do something like this.

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
| config_id |      name       | parent_id |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
|         1 | Main            | null / 0  |
|         2 | Animal products | 1         |
|         3 | Cow             | 2         |
|         4 | Chicken         | 2         |
|         5 | Milk            | 3         |
|         6 | Cheese          | 3         |
|         7 | Egg             | 4         |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
```

This establishes a clear and direct relationship between every configuration. Need to know where eggs comes from? Look up the parent. Need to know what products you get from cows? Take the config_id for Cow and find all the items that lists it as their parent.

EDIT:

Explaining this structure in further detail.

You have your Main configuration (you called it A in your question). Main has a unique ID that identifies it (config_id = 1). Below Main we have our first sub-configuration, I named it "Animal products" in my answer. In its parent_id column it references the config_id of "Main". Basically, it's saying that "Main" is its parent configuration. It is a sub-configuration of "Main".

Below "Animal products" is the next tier of sub-sub-configurations. I have named mine "Cow" and "Chicken". They both reference the config_id of "Animal products" in their respective parent_id columns. They are sub-sub-configurations of "Animal products".

At the bottom there are the products, or sub-sub-sub-configurations. "Milk" and "Cheese" both reference "Cow" as their parent (parent_id 3), while "Egg" references "Chicken" (parent_id 4).

This can continue downwards for as many levels as you need. If you discover that you need specific brands of cheeses (Cheddar or Gouda), you can have them reference "Cheese" as their parent. If you decide that you need a configuration on a level between "Animal products" and "Chicken", you can add a configuration named "Birds". Set it's parent_id to reference the config_id of "Animal products" (1) and then set the parent_id of "Chicken" to reference the config_id of "Birds".

Comment: i'm not understanding this while relating it with my problem. i could be wrong, but maybe a little bit specific?

Comment: Alright, I'll try to explain it. You have your Main configuration (you called it A in your question). Main has a unique ID that identifies it (config_id = 1). Below Main we have our first sub-configuration, I named it "Animal products" in my answer. In its parent_id column it references the config_id of "Main". Basically, it's saying that "Main" is its parent configuration. It is a sub-configuration of "Main".

Comment: Below "Animal products" is the next tier of sub-sub-configurations. I have named mine "Cow" and "Chicken". They both reference the config_id of "Animal products" in their respective parent_id columns. They are sub-sub-configurations of "Animal products".

Comment: At the bottom there are the products, or sub-sub-sub-configurations. "Milk" and "Cheese" both reference "Cow" as their parent (parent_id 3), while "Egg" references "Chicken" (parent_id 4).

Comment: This can continue downwards for as many levels as you need. If you discover that you need specific brands of cheeses (Cheddar or Gouda), you can have them reference "Cheese" as their parent. If you decide that you need a configuration on a level between "Animal products" and "Chicken", you can add a configuration named "Birds". Set it's parent_id to reference the config_id of "Animal products" (1) and then set the parent_id of "Chicken" to reference the config_id of "Birds".

Comment: there is just a little problem, how can i relate the parent_id to an config_id? should i make the config_id primary key and then forgein the parent_id to the config_id?